# extracting the line with a string from a file using python

Tags: python, regex

Team,

I want to extract some lines using a string(starts with tg_) from a file and i get the output as per below regex..the question is,

1. I am not sure how to extract the line if goes for 2 lines ends with `\` like below.
2. I don't know how to remove the special characters with the below existing below regexp.

> *****from a file*******
>
> tg_cr_counters dghbvcvgfv
>
> tg_kk_bb a group1 bye bye bye hi hi hi 1 \ <<<<
>               patch mac hdfh f dgf asadasf \
>               dgfgmnhnjgfg
>
> tg_cr_counters gthghtrhgh }} ]      <<<<<
>
> tg_cr_counters fkgnfkmngvd

```
import re

file = open("C:\\Users\\input.tcl", "r")
f1 = file.readlines()

output = open("extract.txt", "a+")

match_list = [ ]   

for item in f1:

    match_list = re.findall(r'[t][g][_]+\w+.*', item)
    if(len(match_list)>0):
        output.write(match_list[0]+"\r\n")
        print(match_list)
```

Comment: Can we assume that when there is a single newline, then the line is continuing, and that if there are two consecutive newlines it is not? I'm not clear on what you want to extract.

Comment: what  is the end  codition of a multiline match ?

Comment: @JETM the line which i want to grep is a multiline ends with "\" , when i use regex it extracts only the first line which is ending with \, not second and third line

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex with flags for [re.MULTILINE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.M) and [re.DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.S).

This way a `.` will also match `\n` and you can look for anything that starts with `tg_` (no need to put each in `[]`) and ends with a double `\n\n` (or end of text) `\Z`:

```
fn = "t.txt"
with open (fn,"w") as f: 
    f.write("""*****from a file*******

tg_cr_counters dghbvcvgfv

tg_kk_bb a group1 bye bye bye hi hi hi 1 \ <<<<
patch mac hdfh f dgf asadasf \
dgfgmnhnjgfg

tg_cr_counters gthghtrhgh }} ] <<<<<

tg_cr_counters fkgnfkmngvd
""")

import re

with open("extract.txt", "a+") as o, open(fn) as f:
    for m in re.findall(r'^tg_.*?(?:\n\n|\Z)', f.read(), flags=re.M|re.S):
        o.write("-"*40+"\r\n")
        o.write(m)
        o.write("-"*40+"\r\n")

with open("extract.txt")as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output (each match is between a line of `----------------------------------------`):

```
----------------------------------------
tg_cr_counters dghbvcvgfv

----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
tg_kk_bb a group1 bye bye bye hi hi hi 1 \ <<<<
patch mac hdfh f dgf asadasf dgfgmnhnjgfg

----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
tg_cr_counters gthghtrhgh }} ] <<<<<

----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
tg_cr_counters fkgnfkmngvd
----------------------------------------
```

`re.findall()` result looks like:

```
['tg_cr_counters dghbvcvgfv\n\n', 
 'tg_kk_bb a group1 bye bye bye hi hi hi 1 \\ <<<<\npatch mac hdfh f dgf asadasf dgfgmnhnjgfg\n\n', 
 'tg_cr_counters gthghtrhgh }} ] <<<<<\n\n', 
 'tg_cr_counters fkgnfkmngvd\n']
```

To enable multiline-searches you need to read in more then one line at a time - if your file is *humongeous* this will lead to memory problems.

Comment: thanks..but you are trying to extract form the output, it is there to extract from the input file where multilines are present starting with tg_

Comment: @CharlesDaniel I am creating a file that holds all the lines on top of the code. Then I am extracting from the whole file ` f.read()` the lines you see between `--------------------` - they are multiline matches. I don't quite get what you imply... `t.txt` holds 4 multilines starting with `tg_` and a line in front with `'*****from a file*******'` in it that is not captured because it does not start with `tg_`